# ISO human-readable parser for Python in Python

Tags: python, parsing, recursive-descent

I'm looking for a parser for Python (preferably v. 2.7) written in human-readable Python.  Performance or flexibility are not important.  The accuracy/correctness of the parsing and the clarity of the parser's code are far more important considerations here.

Searching online I've found a few parser *generators* that generate human-readable Python code, but I have not found the corresponding Python grammar to go with any of them (from what I could see, they all follow different grammar specification conventions).  At any rate, even if I could find a suitable parser-generator/Python grammar combo, a readily available Python *parser* that fits my requirements (human-readable Python code) is naturally far more preferable.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[PyPy](http://pypy.org/) is a Python implementation written entirely in Python. I am not an expert, but here's the link to their parser which - obviously - has been written in Python itself:

https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/819faa2129a8/pypy/interpreter/pyparser

Comment: Thanks, this looked promising at first, but, AFAICT, PythonParser is not documented, and I can't figure out how to use it from reading the source (not a good sign if readability is a requirement)...

Comment: @kjo - Not sure what you mean by "not documented" (=what you expected to find). The source code has quite a bit of information on the workings of the module. Since programming language parsers are not usually meant for direct use by developers who code in that language, I doubt you will find a lot of "website documentation" in the form of - for example - the one you can browse at http://docs.python.org/ ... or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: I can't find how to generate the arguments required to instantiate a parser object; in particular, its `__init__` has a "state" argument that is very hard to pin down.  The source code certainly does not say a word about what this argument is supposed to be (what class, etc.).  After a lot of searching I was able to find some bits of (very high-level) info, widely scattered over several pages, on these "states", but not enough to tell me how to instantiate a state, so that I can instantiate a parser, and pass it a string of Python source code.  If you know how to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should invest your effort in [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html). An excerpt from the python docs.

> The ast module helps Python applications to process trees of the
>   Python abstract syntax grammar. The abstract syntax itself might
>   change with each Python release; this module helps to find out
>   programmatically what the current grammar looks like.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question.  `ast.parse` does nothing more than call the built-in `compile` function.  How is that a "human-readable parser for Python in Python"?